# Processing a CSV with colon separated pairs in fields

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I have a CSV in the format of

```
Fruit:Apple,Seeds:Yes,Colour:Red or Green
Fruit:Orange,Seeds:No,Colour:Orange
Fruit:Pear,Seeds:Yes,Colour:Green,Shape:Odd
Fruit:Banana,Seeds:No,Colour:Yellow,Shape:Also Odd
```

and I want to be able to use create a JSON object for these values that looks something like

```
{"requestdata":{
 "testdata":"example",
 "testcategory":"category",
 "fruits":{
          "Fruit":{
                 "value":"Apple"
                 "type":"string"},
           "Seeds":{
                  "value":"Yes"
                  "type":"bool"}
            }
```

etc

I know I can load the CSV with a delimiter of my choosing, but how would I specify the second delimiter? Or should I try and build a dictionary instead for each cell of data and treat it as a string to split?

Comment: That doesn't look like a csv format. I would just write a simple parser by hand.

Comment: Construct a finite automaton for it. The only *special* characters you need to recognise are `:` ,  `,`,  `\n` (,and EOF)

Comment: @HåkenLid - Agreed- unforunately it's what my application offers when "exporting to csv" - it's frustrating that it could've easily been a "true" CSV with header values, etc, but they chose instead to make pairs. I'll follow awiebe's comments and simply split each "cell" to give me my pairs.

Comment: CSV does not have a standard, unlike json, xml etc. So if your app calls this CSV, that's not technically "wrong". But json is typically the best choice for data export (if available). Since it's a very simple, readable, well defined and ubiquitous format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just split on the comma and use a string split to process the remaining elements, building a dictionary, then have the json module produce JSON from the dictionary.  It is fairly easy to create malformed JSON when trying to be clever with text processing, such as

- Forgetting to quote keys.
- Quoting Values you didn't mean to
- Not escaping JSON special characters

Building the dictionary and then having the moule do its thing will make your code much more maintainable and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense to me. I was worried that I was "over-engineering" it but didn't want to miss any obvious shortcuts that could've gotten me to my destination faster!